# jq - Filtering JSON array if does not contains not working

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I'm having trouble parsing a JSON file from which I would like to extract elements that does not contains the string "To Do" as label.

Here is the file I'm trying to parse

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Task A",
    "labels": [
      "Low",
      "To Do"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Task B",
    "labels": [
      "Medium",
      "Done"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Task C",
    "labels": [
      "High",
      "To Do"
    ]
  }
]
```

I can successfully extract elements which contains "To Do" with the following command :

```
$ cat tmp.json | jq 'keys[] as $k | select(.[$k].labels[] | contains("To Do")) | "\(.[$k].id) -- \(.[$k].title) -- \(.[$k].labels)"'
"1 -- Task A -- [\"Low\",\"To Do\"]"
"3 -- Task C -- [\"High\",\"To Do\"]"
```

However when I negate the condition jq has the following behaviour :

```
$ cat tmp.json | jq 'keys[] as $k | select(.[$k].labels[] | contains("To Do") | not) | "\(.[$k].id) -- \(.[$k].title) -- \(.[$k].labels)"'
"1 -- Task A -- [\"Low\",\"To Do\"]"
"2 -- Task B -- [\"Medium\",\"Done\"]"
"2 -- Task B -- [\"Medium\",\"Done\"]"
"3 -- Task C -- [\"High\",\"To Do\"]"
```

The only difference here is the condition's negation, but all three elements are printed and the one I want to filter is printed twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query seems overcomplicated for such a trivial task (I didn't debug but you're probably misusing `contains` there; I suspect it's run for each array element, not just once for the array itself).

Anyway, here is a clean and straightforward approach:

```
.[] | select(.labels | index("To Do") | not) | "\(.id) -- \(.title) -- \(.labels)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with `all(_; . != "To Do")`:

```
.[] 
| select( all(.labels[]; . != "To Do"))
|  "\(.id) -- \(.title) -- \(.labels)"
```